# Google People API notes

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

In Google's People API, is it possible to access/change contact's notes?
[Person definition](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person)

When a contact is created https://contacts.google.com/, it is possible to set the field "Notes", that's what I'm looking for.

As of now, I'm using the official NodeJS API and the "UserDefined" for this purpose.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **notes** field in https://contacts.google.com corresponds to the [biography](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#biography) field on the person.

Comment: my hero, that's not mentioned in the documentation