# Google People API notes field

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'd like to know how to get the 'notes' field from the Google people API. There's no equivalent in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get). I tried "biographies" but that didn't return any notes when I called the API for names, emails, etc.

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007060/google-people-api-notes) asked a few years ago but I know the API has changed a bit and was hoping someone knows the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

*The `biographies` field still representing the `notes`*

### How to check it?

1. Create a contact setting the notes with a concrete string, i.e. `Hey, I'am a note`
2. Call [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

   - resourceName = `people/me`
   - personFields = `names`
3. Get the `resourceName` to use it later
4. Call [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

   - resourceName = `resource from point 3`
   - personFields = `biographies`
5. Check the `biographies` field, it will look something like:

```
  "biographies": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "randomId"
        }
      },
      "value": "Hey, I'am a note",
      "contentType": "TEXT_PLAIN"
    }
```

### References

- [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)
- [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

Answer (score 0):

**Example in PHP:**

```
$q = $service->people->searchContacts([
    'query' => '0777677305',
    'readMask' => 'emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,biographies',
]);

foreach ($q as $person)
{
    $per = $person->getPerson();
    $data = $per->toSimpleObject();
    
    print_r($data);
    
    foreach ($data->biographies as $bio)
    {
        $found_contact_note = $bio->value;
    }
}
```