# Adding Notes value to Google Contact

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I am using using Google.Apis.PeopleService to create a new contact under my account and everything works fine.
But there is only one thing i can't get - How to add Notes to a contact? I couldn't find that field. Thanks

[image: Contact Notes]

Below is a piece of code which I use

```
        var request = service.People.CreateContact(new Person()
        {

            Names = new List<Name>() { new Name() { GivenName = givenName, FamilyName = familyName } },
            EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>() { new EmailAddress() { Value = emailAddress } },
            PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>() { new PhoneNumber() { Value = phoneNumber } },
        
        }); ;
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007060/google-people-api-notes)

Comment: Yes, thanks it answers